# Why did the State Department entertain the founder of the Taliban?

Tags: united-states, international-relations, taliban, state-department

I saw an [image of the former Secretary of State, Mike Pompeo](https://www.voanews.com/middle-east/pompeo-meets-afghan-taliban-negotiators-qatar) I believe, standing in a formal room with the founder of the Taliban.

Can anyone help me understand why we as a democratic nation would entertain this organization?  Their modus operandi is spreading terror.  They are known for killing, raping and destroying irreplaceable relics.  Does this meeting imply that the former administration was sympathetic to this kind of regimes?

Comment: The linked article said it all, what questions remain? Also, please name the "**Taliban Founder**" in the photo.

Comment: You could accuse the US of the same things, it's all relative.

Comment: The US is not a militant state who only seeks to spread terror.  Take it easy, chum.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Then Secretary of State Pompeo met with Mullah Baradar (pictured in the France24 article) on the 21st of November 2020 to discuss the Afghanistan peace process. According to [Frace24](https://www.france24.com/en/middle-east/20201121-us-secretary-of-state-pompeo-meets-afghan-govt-taliban-negotiators-in-qatar):

> Pompeo met separately with the Afghan government and Taliban negotiation teams in a luxury hotel in the Qatari capital.
>
> "I would be most interested in getting your thoughts on how we can increase the probability of a successful outcome," Pompeo said as he met the Afghan government side, noting the shared interest in such a scenario.

On the 15th of August 2021, Pompeo was asked about these negotiations on Fox News Sunday. [The Hill wrote](https://thehill.com/homenews/sunday-talk-shows/567924-pompeo-says-trump-administration-didnt-take-the-words-of-taliban) about that:

> “Do you regret giving the Taliban that legitimacy? Do you regret pressing the Afghan government to release 5,000 prisoners, which they did, some of whom are now back on the battlefield fighting with the Taliban?” Wallace asked Pompeo after playing a clip of the former secretary of State from March of last year in which he said Taliban negotiators would work alongside the U.S.
>
> “Chris, you make peace with your enemies. The statement that I made that day was absolutely true. You can ask the military leaders on the ground. We did good work to crush al Qaeda. When we left office, there were fewer than 200 al Qaeda left in Afghanistan,” Pompeo said.
>
> “Chris, we never trusted the Taliban. You can ask them yourselves. We made abundantly clear: If they did not live up to that piece of paper, to the words that they had put on the ground, we weren't going to allow them to just walk away from any deal that they struck. We were going to go crush them,” he added.
>
> In March, Pompeo said, “The gentlemen that I met with agreed that they would break that relationship and that they would work alongside of us ... and to have al Qaeda depart from that place.”
>
> Pompeo oversaw negotiations with the Taliban during the Trump administration, which had come to an agreement to withdraw U.S. troops by May 1. In July, Pompeo told The Associated Press that he applauded Biden's move to withdraw troops from the country but worried that counterterrorism efforts by the U.S. could be impacted.

Wikipedia has [an overview of the Afghan peace process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Afghan_peace_process). The reason for the US to send a high ranking official (Secretary Pompeo) was to negotiate the terms of the US withdrawal from Afghanistan. According to [that Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Afghan_peace_process):

> The provisions of the deal include the withdrawal of all American and NATO troops from Afghanistan, a Taliban pledge to prevent al-Qaeda from operating in areas under Taliban control, and talks between the Taliban and the Afghan government. The United States agreed to an initial reduction of its force level from 13,000 to 8,600 by July 2020, followed by a full withdrawal within 14 months if the Taliban keeps its commitments. The United States also committed to closing five military bases within 135 days, and expressed its intent to end economic sanctions on the Taliban by August 27, 2020.

Reaching such an agreement, and diplomacy in general, requires talking to representatives from other countries and groups, even if there are very few shared values between those involved.